# Need to split string with brackets

Tags: c#

I have a string which in parentheses and need to split it.

```
(Key value) (Key_Name val1 val2) (Key value) (Key_1 Value) (TESTS Key1 Key2 (Key3 Value)) (Key Value 0.0) (Key_1 (Key value) (Key value))
```

And i need the value it like

```
(Key value)     
(Key_Name val1 val2)     
(Key value)     
(Key_1 Value)     
(TESTS Key1 Key2 (Key3 Value))     
(Key Value 0.0)     
(Key_1 (Key value) (Key value))
```

Plz suggest.

i try this with below regex

```
\((.*?)\)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reach the desired result by using the `for loop` and `counting the outer parentheses`:

```
string s = "(Key value) (Key_Name val1 val2) (Key value) (Key_1 Value) (TESTS Key1 Key2 (Key3 Value)) (Key Value 0.0) (Key_1 (Key value) (Key value))";

List<string> list = new List<string>();
string keyValue = "(";
int itemIndex = 0;
int numberP = 1;
for(int i=1; i<s.Length;i++)
{
    if (s[i] == '(')
          numberP++;
    else if (s[i] == ')')
          numberP--;
    keyValue = keyValue + s[i];
    if(numberP==0)
     {
          if(keyValue.Trim()!="")
                list.Add(keyValue.Trim());
          keyValue = "";
     }
}
```

**[result](https://dotnetfiddle.net/31VKNt):**

```
(Key value)
(Key_Name val1 val2)
(Key value)
(Key_1 Value)
(TESTS Key1 Key2 (Key3 Value))
(Key Value 0.0)
(Key_1 (Key value) (Key value))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
string s = "(Key value) (Key_Name val1 val2) (Key value) (Key_1 Value) (TESTS Key1 Key2 (Key3 Value)) (Key Value 0.0) (Key_1 (Key value) (Key value))";

Regex regex = new Regex(@"\(([^)]*)\)");
string[] result = regex.Matches(s).Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).ToArray();
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/wryFO5

Comment: The desired result is `(Key_1 (Key value) (Key value))` must be an item...